# inserting a function value into a stored procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm having trouble calling a function and using the value from the function call within my stored procedure using mySQL.  My function extracts a date value. I'm attempting to set the parameter values with my  stored procedure call (parameters - data_transfer_id, mode).  Is this possible?

Your help is appreciated.  My code below is incorrect but is my start.  The function name is kettle_data_transfer.f_DT_last_transfer (data_transfer_id, mode).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sproc_DT_consumer_answer_data` 
(IN data_transfer_id bigint (20),
IN `mode` varchar(25)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE last_transfer date kettle_data_transfer.f_DT_last_transfer(data_transfer_id, mode);

SELECT 
  CEQ.consumer_ID
, EM.event_mapping_ID
, F.footprint_ID
, F.create_DTM as footprint_create_DTM
, EM.event_ID
, EL.brand_ID
, RELAT.activity_type_ID
, ED.event_ID as footprint_event_ID
FROM kettle_data_transfer.Event_Mappings EM
JOIN kettle_data_transfer.Consumer_Event_Queue CEQ ON CEQ.event_ID = EM.event_ID
JOIN efn.Footprints F ON F.consumer_ID = CEQ.consumer_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN efn.Event_Days ED on ED.event_day_ID = F.event_day_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN efn.R_Event_Location_Activity_Type RELAT ON RELAT.r_elat_ID = F.r_elat_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN efn.Event_Locations EL on EL.event_location_ID = RELAT.event_location_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN kettle_data_transfer.Records RR on RR.consumer_ID = CEQ.consumer_ID
WHERE EM.active_flag = 1
AND F.sample_flag = 0
AND RR.failure_code = 0
AND RR.`ignore` = 0
and (CEQ.modify_DTM > last_transfer OR EM.create_DTM > last_transfer)
and (RR.mode = `mode` OR EM.mode =  `mode`)
and (RR.data_transfer_ID  = data_transfer_id OR EM.data_transfer_ID = data_transfer_id )
and (RR.consumer_ID = CEQ.consumer_ID)
AND (ED.event_ID = CEQ.event_ID OR ED.event_ID is null)
GROUP BY CEQ.consumer_ID, EL.brand_ID

END
```

Comment: Have you tried using the function call in a separate `SET last_transfer ` statement instead of the `DECLARE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for stored program variable declarations:

```
DECLARE var_name [, var_name] ... type [DEFAULT value]
```

`DEFAULT value` is not saying "default value goes here."  It's the keyword `DEFAULT`, followed by an expression containing the initial value for the variable.

You are trying to set the default initial value of the variable, but you have omitted the `DEFAULT` keyword after the variable name.

Adding it should resolve the issue.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-local-variable.html

Comment: Unrelated tip: when using a stored function inside a stored procedure, you don't need to qualify the function name with the database name, if the function is in the same db schema as the procedure.  MySQL does an implicit `USE` of the database where the procedure is declared when execution begins, and reverts it if needed when the procedure ends, so it will always find a function in the same schema, no matter which db might have been your current db when you call the procedure.